# Printing or Exporting OrientDB Graphs

Tags: graph, printing, orientdb

I am new to OrientDB. Once I render a graph can I print it or save it as a SVG file or PDF? I am coming from Neo4j where I am able to save the graphical output as a SVG file. Can someone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You could just copy the `<svg>` from page source:

[image]